# Regex to Match All Except a String

Tags: regex

Given the string `beginend` where `begin` and `end` are both optional, I want to match the whole string and back-reference only `begin`. `Begin` is unknown but alpha-numeric; `end` is literally `end`. How would I go about doing this?

In case it matters, I'd be using this in a Textpad macro to replace "beginend" with something else including "begin".

Comment: Can you use an example to better describe what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To match an string of "alpha-numeric" characters that do not contain "end" you can use something like:

```
(?:(?!end)[A-Za-z\d])+
```

An expression like this would do what you ask:

```
^((?:(?!end)[A-Za-z0-9])+)(?:end)?\z
```

Comment: For some reason, this results in no match found. I don't completely understand what it is you're doing. Why are you using + instead of * ? Why are you using ?: in the back-reference (the part I want to save)? What does ?! mean?

Comment: @user1157244, TextPad does not support lookarounds last I checked, so this expression will not work. I missed that part of the question. :/

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** (see after blockquote)

> I don't have commenting privileges, so I can't comment on his
>   solution, but Qtax's solution will not work because it assumes that
>   `begin` will never contain the substring "end", e.g., it wouldn't
>   match the string "sendingend".
>
> My solution:
>       `^([A-Za-z0-9]*)(?:end)?$`
>
> Of course, it also depends on what you mean by *alphanumeric*. My
>   example has the strictest definition, i.e., just upper- and lower-case
>   letters plus digits. You'd need to add in other characters if you want
>   them. If you want to include the underscore as well as those
>   characters, you can replace the whole bulky `[A-Za-z0-9]` with `\w`
>   (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`). Add `\s` if you want whitespace.
>
> Since you said your regex knowledge is limited, I'll explain the rest
>   of the solution to you and whoever else comes along.
>
> - `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the string, respectively. <strike>By including the `$` in particular, you're
>     guaranteeing that the last "end" you encounter is really at the end.
>     For example, without them, it would still match the string
>     "sendingsending" and the rest of your program would think it's found
>     that "end" at the end. With these, it's still going to match
>     "sendingsending" because any characters are allowed (see below), but
>     other steps in your script will recognize the presence of
>     "end".</strike> It actually doesn't matter much for this current
>     string, because the `([A-Za-z0-9]*)` will capture the entire string if
>     "end" is not present. However, you therefore need another regex to
>     ensure the presence or absence of "end"...so you'd do something like
>     `(end)$` to locate it.
> - `([A-Za-z0-9]*)`: the square brackets contain the specific characters that are allowed (you should definitely read up on this if
>     you don't know). The `*` means it will match one of those characters 0
>     or more times, so this allows for no string (i.e., just "end") as well
>     as super-long strings. The parentheses are capturing that pattern so
>     you can back-reference it.
> - `(?:end)?`: the last `?` makes it match this pattern 0 or 1 times (i.e., makes it optional). The `(?:string)` structure allows you to
>     group characters together as you would with parentheses but the `?:`
>     makes it *not* save that pattern, so it uses less memory. In your
>     case, that memory would be negligible, but it's nice to know for
>     future use.
>
> If you need more help, try Googling 'regex'. There's tons of good
>   references. You can also test them out. My personal favourite tester
>   is called [My Regex Tester](http://myregextester.com/index.php).
>
> Good luck!

I just tried looking up TextPad macros, and you might run into a problem. As I've explained above, to verify the presence of "end" at the end of the string, you'll need something separate. I was envisioning some kind of conditional, something like IF `(end)$` THEN replace with `^([A-Za-z0-9]*)(?:end)?$` ELSE use the whole string. However, I don't know if you can do that with these macros...it's hard to say, because I'm not a TextPad user and there's next to no documentation. If you can't, then I think you're going to have to put some restrictions on it. One idea is to not allow "end" to be anywhere in the `begin` substring (which is how Qtax's solution did it). But now I'm wondering...if "end" if going to be optional, and if conditionals aren't allowed, what's the point of having it at all? ...perhaps I'm overthinking things. I await your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Unfortunately, the back-reference contains "beginend" - "end" is not excluded. Your comments make it sound like Qtax's solution should work (begin will never contain "end"), but it doesn't work either.

Comment: To clarify what I'm trying to do: I would select a string and then use the macro to find the pattern and replace it with xxxbeginxxx. So far, I'm getting xxxbeginendxxx. The reason everything is optional is that I would also like to be able to use the macro to just get xxxxxx if I don't select a string first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a positive look-ahead. This is a zero-width assertion so won't be included in the match. It also allows for the substring `end` to be present within the alpha-numeric string

```
([a-z0-9]*)(?=end)
```

What this is saying is: Match an alpha-numeric string only if it is immediately followed by `end`

Comment: That won't work because "end" is optional. What does ?= mean?

Comment: Ah yes. Missed that bit. `(?=...)` is a [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which means match the preceding regex only if immediately followed by whatever is in the look-ahead